# “measureLine” not working in pyqgis 3.0

Tags: pyqgis, python-3

The following code works very well in pyqgis 2.0 with a line shapefile, but when executed with pyqgis 3.0 the instruction measureLine return 0 and with no errors signaled.
What is the new instruction in pyqgis 3.0?

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

def dist_seg():
  layer=iface.activeLayer()
  L=[]
  features = layer.getFeatures()
  d = QgsDistanceArea()
  for i,element in enumerate (features):
    m = d.measureLine(element.geometry().asPolyline())
    L.append ((i,round(m,1)))
  return L
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the version of QGis 3.0.2-1 has an issue with "measureLine". I upgrade to QGis 3.0.3-1 and the code is now working very well.